# Stream video from a database in Java

Tags: java, database, video, jmf

I have to stream some videos from a database. I planned to use Java Media Framework, because I get the Blob objects from the result of a query, but apparently JMF cannot play videos from streams, but only from URLs. Does Anyone know how to solve this problem? If JMF cannot solve it, someone can recommend me a different framework?

Comment: would this help? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574143/stream-video-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [register a protocol handler](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/), and then use this special URL within JMF. Registering protocol handlers is a bit complicated in my view, but there are a many [examples](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1434) on the internet.

Comment: Really interesting, I create my protocol and I can read from the stream. Unfortunately JMF can't read MP4, but your answer was very useful.