# Live video streaming in java

Tags: java, video, jmf

I need to add live webcam video streaming facility to my web app where multiple clients can see live video.It's almost like a virtual classroom where the teacher will teach live and the students will watch.How can I broadcast live video in java .I have decided using spring framework for the application . Many seem to suggest xuggler or JMF, but I have not found any working examples of them yet. Can anyone please suggest which library to use and examples for the purpose ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why has this post gotten so many -1's? I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 5):

This question is already answered and the below link has the details. I would recommend "user3680660" to look into the answers provided.

[Stream video in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574143/stream-video-in-java)

The link explains Xuggler and Amazon's cloud front.

Comment: If you're in this situation again (question answered in another Stack Overflow question), can you flag as duplicate please?

Comment: That answer is old as hell. And not relevant already.