# Java lan video chatting

Tags: java, video-streaming, lan, video-conversion

I want to build a project of `video chatting + messaging` by **java** without `internet connection` through `*lan*`. But i can't get any idea about ***what to do and how to do?*** I am beginner in `java GUI`. So I want to know the topics that i have to learn and from where?

Comment: Break it down into pieces, like this: 1. Learn how to transfer data between two computers. 2. Learn how to capture video from a webcam. 3. Learn how to display video on the screen. 4. Learn how to capture audio from a microphone. 5. Learn how to play audio through the speakers. 6. Learn how to send video over that connection you made back in step 1. 7. Learn how to send audio over that connection you made back in step 1. 8. Put the audio and video parts together........

Comment: @immibis thanks for the comment. But i want to stream video from my pc to another pc live and vice versa like skype. How can i do that?

Comment: @ShubhashisRoyDipta by doing all of those 8 things (plus any things I've missed).

Comment: @ShubhashisRoyDipta: what you want to do is not a simple task that can be accomplish in a day or two. You must learn and that's the only way to do anything. No one will tell you exact sequence of steps. Because usually  if you know exact sequence you write own software and sell it :-). Of course, there is a simple way: if you need something like Skype, just install Skype. In any case I wish you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

well, you will need to look up data streaming, showing video stream on panel and socket and protocol manipulation in the java docs and other online guides. those are the foundation you will need for the project. as for the GUI, it is not hard.. there are many tutorials out there.

if you face a problem we will help, but we will NOT do it for you... start something first.
examples:

[GUI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4a_GUI.html)

[Network basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html)

[Video streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574143/stream-video-in-java)

do your research... that is the way to learn
also, research steps of making (analyzing) a project