# Stream video from Java webserver to browser

Tags: javascript, java, webserver, video-streaming, webrtc

I have a webserver written in Java with the Jetty framework. The computer running the server is connected to a webcam, and I want to be able to stream video from the webcam to browsers connected to the server.

I already have code that can get the pixel data from each frame of the webcam either raw or encoded as a jpeg.

I need to be able to deploy the webserver as a JAR, so pure Java solutions are ideal. I can't use libraries that depend on for example FFmpeg.

How should I go about streaming the video to a browser? Here are some possible ideas I had:

- Send jpeg data through WebSocket and decode in Javascript on the other end
- Somehow use webRTC
- I know that network cameras can stream video viewable in a browser, so maybe there is a Java library to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574143/stream-video-in-java

Comment: @Blue Thanks, that question has answers that might be useful to me. However, I ask if there is a solution that doesn't require native dependencies, only Java libraries.

Comment: If the libraries mentioned (xuggle, stream.m) don't work w/o built-in imports, you could always put the native stuff in the jar as well (copy-paste into your workspace). That's assuming you really need this to run w/o the native libraries present in nearly every Java installation.