# vlcj webcam stream in java

Tags: java, vlcj

I am trying to make a simple program that will live stream from my webcam.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int port = nextAvailable();
    //String media = "/root/Desktop/525600.mp4";
    String media = "/dev/video0";
    String[] options = {":sout=#duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:"+port+"/stream},dst=display}", ":sout-all", ":sout-keep"};
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media,options);
    System.out.println("Using port: "+port);
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}
```

if I use the commented media (/root/Desktop/525600.mp4), the stream works without any issues. However, I do not know how to stream from the webcam. I tried /dev/video0 but it gives the following errors:

> [00007fae70008f78] core access error: read error: Invalid argument
>
> [00007fae70008f78] filesystem access error: read error: Invalid
>   argument
>
> [00007fae7000d3d8] core stream error: cannot pre fill buffer

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please look in this post : [Java Video Streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574143/stream-video-in-javahttp://)

Comment: I will look into Xuggler... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replaced

```
String media = "/dev/video0";
```

with

```
String media = "v4l2:///dev/video0";
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can refer to this :-

https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-live-streaming

Comment: Oh that also uses Xuggler... apparently Xuggler is discontinued?

Comment: discontinued in the sense , they are not active now. but their API works :)